# Equivalent definition to holomorphic vector bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, holomorphic-bundles

Let $\pi:E \rightarrow M$ be a complex vector bundle over a complex manifold $M$. Prove that if there exists a complex structure on $E$ as a manifold, such that the projection $\pi$ is holomorphic then $E$ has a holomorphic structure. This condition means that there is an open cover of $M$ such that if $U$ is in this open cover then there is a diffeomorphism $\psi_U:\pi^{-1}(U) \rightarrow U \times \mathbf{C}^k$ such that $\pi|_{\pi^{-1}(U)} = pr_U \circ \psi_U$ and the transition functions $g_{UV}:U \cap V \rightarrow CL(n,\mathbf{C})$ are holomorphic (where $\psi_U \psi_V^{-1}(x,v)=(x,g_{UV}(x)v)$.

I can easily prove the converse but I am struggling to proof this statement.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about this exercise. I guess you want the $\psi_U$ do become holomorphic, then it is clear that $g_{UV}$ is also holomorphic. But you might have to change the complex structure on $E$ to make this work? Take for example the trivial bundle $E=\mathbb C \times  M\to M$. Then you can endow $E$ with a "weird" complex structure, by choosing a $C^\infty$-diffeomorphism $\varphi: \mathbb C \to D$, where $D\subset\mathbb C$ is the unit disk. So as a complex manifold, $E$ is isomorphic to $D\times M$, but *not* to $\mathbb C\times M$, because $\mathbb C$ is not biholomorphic to $D$.

Comment: Where did you encounter this problem?

Comment: @red_trumpet this is exercise 2 on page 75 in Moroianu `lectures on Kaehler geometry'. I am not understanding your previous comment: how do you endow $E$ with a weird complex structure? If I understand your argument correctly, $D\times M$ IS isomorphic to $\mathbf{C} \times M$ as complex line bundles, by the isomorphism $\varphi \times id$. I am not sure if you are confusing complex vector bundles with holomorphic vector bundles.

Comment: The map $\varphi \times id: \mathbb C \times M \to \mathbb D \times M$ is a smooth diffeomorphism. But not an isomorphism of complex manifolds! (Note that the unit disc is not isomorphic to $\mathbb C$, by Liouville's theorem: $\mathbb C$ does not admit bounded non-constant holomorphic functions, but $D$ does). We can then define the "weird" complex structure on $\mathbb C \times M$ by pulling-back the ordinary/product complex structure on $D \times M$ along $\varphi \times id$. So the fibers of the holomorphic map $E \to M$ are as complex manifolds $D$, not $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Dear @red_trumpet, thanks for your comment. I agree that $\mathbf{C}\times M$ and $D \times M$ are not isomorphic (via $\varphi \times id$) as complex manifolds, but they are isomorphic as complex line bundles (as we are not talking about holomorphic bundles $\varphi \times id$ gives the isomorphism). To solve the exercise, as you mentioned in the first comment I think we need to show that the $\psi_U$ are holomorphic.